# Command json-server --watch db.json is not working - it returns"'json-server' command not found"

Tags: node.js, json, npm, npm-install, json-server

I set a JSON file to use as a little practice database, but I can't run the server.

I've already tried to install (and reinstall) json-server global and locally `npm install -g json-server` and `npm install json-server` and then run `json-server --watch db.json`, but it doesn't work.

I've also tried to set a script in the package.json file `"load": "json-server --watch db.json"` and run the script `node load`.

But nothing seems to work and I keep getting in return the message:

> "'json-server' command not found"

or, in Portuguese:

> "'json-server' não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes".

How can I fix this?

Comment: if the `json-server` command isnt available in your terminal than the global npm packages are likely not being loaded correctly

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please attach the exact code you are trying to run to build a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please edit your question rather than clarifying in the comment section:)

Comment: @MarcellTóth 


In the VSCode integrated terminal, I install json-server globally: 

npm install -g json-server

I navigate to the db.json folder through the terminal by changing directory.


Then I try to run the server:


json-server --watch db.json


However, I keep getting those massages in return, but npm and Node are working fine, the json-server folder is installed inside the node modules and as one of the dependencies in the package.json.


I also tried to add a script to the package.json file:


"load": "json-server --watch db.json"

Comment: @Flame

I've just tested here. By getting the prefix and navigating to the folder, I find a json-server.cmd file there and I can force running the server there by typing `json-server.cmd --watch db.json`, but then I face another problem, because that prefix doesn't lead me to my projects directory and a simple copy and paste doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Flame Do you know how can I solve the problem and load the global npm packages correctly?

Answer (score 30):

Try:

```
npx json-server --watch db.json
```

Comment: this helped me - but why?

Comment: this way with npx also works for me 

Comment: The npx command is a way to run packages without having to install them globally.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution**:
For Linux:

1. Firstly, run this command to globally install json-server

   `sudo npm install -g json-server`
2. Move to your local folder(like my-app) and run this command

   `npm install json-server`
3. Open a new Terminal in the same folder

   `json-server --watch db.json --port 3004`

Answer (score 1):

Check if this might help you.

Open the git bash(assume you have on your local machine) and execute below command:
**alias json-server="<..../node_modules/.bin/json-server.cmd>"**   *---> IGNORE <, > symbols and .... is the location where your node_modules folder is present*

Then run 
**json-server --watch db.json**

Answer (score 1):

I added the script for running the json-server in my `package.json` file like this:

```js
 "server": "json-server db.json --watch --port 5000"
```

And tried to run it like this:

```js
npm run server
```

And it works except the server wasn't being watched unless I had to manually end and run the json server command every time a change was made.

What fixed it for me was running the command directly in a bash terminal (under the app root directory).

So run:

```js
json-server db.json --watch --port 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here first you can install JSON-server global...
to do that in your project terminal you can run `npm i -g json-server`

after that, you can install json server for your project using `npm i json-server`

The next step is you can run the server by using `json-server --watch db.json --port 8000`

so in here you can change the port ,including port which port you can run your json db.

Answer (score 0):

I also stacked this kind of problem and solved it with this method:

All credit goes to @MarcellToth

@MarcellTóth In the VSCode integrated terminal, I install json-server globally: npm install -g json-server I navigate to the db.json folder through the terminal by changing directory. Then I try to run the server: json-server --watch db.json However, I keep getting those massages in return, but npm and Node are working fine, the json-server folder is installed inside the node modules and as one of the dependencies in the package.json. I also tried to add a script
to the package.json file: "load": "json-server --watch db.json" –
Angelo Fonseca
Mar 14, 2019 at 19:25

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).